# Voltage step up module and if I am using it correctly

Tags: voltage, batteries, audio, boost, converter

I am making a ***"simple"*** bluetooth speaker and have followed instructions from a **[Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wtdtcyrtbFw)** video on  how to assemble the components I have bought.

However... I am finding that the rechargeable li-po battery that I am using for power in conjunction with a protection circuit and voltage boost module doesn't seem to want to do so...

Could somebody tell me what would be the best way forwards?

**[This](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Boost-Module-2A-Step-Up-Converter-2V-24V-To-5V-9V-12V-28V-Power-Supply-Board/163477927511?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&var=462835879866&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649)** is the module I am using, and **[this](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Genuine-Panasonic-18650-3400mAh-Rechargeable-Battery-NCR18650B-Li-ion-Flat-Top/253617066273?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&var=552842659064&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649)** the battery.

The battery is rated for 3.7V as written on the side of it, but when connected to **[this](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/1S-3-7V-2A-BMS-PCM-18650-Lipo-Battery-Protection-Board-PCB-Lithium-li-on-Battery/143080534769?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649)** battery protection circuit it seems to drop to 3.4V (assuming for protection purposes?).

Given that I am working with 3.4V at FULL charge, I charge up an then switch the circuit on and adjust the boost module to output a steady 6.5V as per the Youtube video. I assume this is done such that as the battery is drained and the voltage reduces, the boost will remain above the 4.5V required to power **[this](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Bluetooth-amplifier-board-module-AUX-audio-receiver-BK3260-stereo-V4-2-5W-5w-amp/332647887429?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649)** bluetooth amp board...

Could somebody please inform me if I am wrong about this?

Just FYI, the speaker works perfectly when I am powering through the micro-USB cable connected to a wall charger.

I am new to the world of hobbyist electronics, so my knowledge is limited.

**Update (more info)**
I just had a quick test of the voltages throughout the system with my multimeter.

- Battery terminals: 3.2V
- Protection board output: 2.5V
- Booster V-in: 2.5V
- Booster V-out: Varying unstably between 3.5 and 4.2V (I did not have a capacitor connected across the V-out terminals at this time)

I have drawn a very rudimentary diagram to hopefully explain my layout:
[image]

Comment: Ask a specific question, you'll get better answers

Comment: There should be practically no drop in the protection module.  Insert every wry, dire, or outright rude thing you've ever heard about eBay here -- if you buy from a flea market, expect flea-market quality...  You need to find a better module.  That sort of voltage drop is **not** inherent in battery protection circuits.

Comment: @TimWescott - I understand completely. If there were an electronics shop nearby, I'd have gone there :-( I will have a go at re-soldering the protection circuit later to see if I can improve. I feel that it may be my crappy soldering that may have also inhibited progress, but I will investigate further and report back :-)

Comment: @TimWescott - Your hunch is indeed correct. It looks like the protection circuit is a duff one. I tested the whole thing with a new battery connected to the circuit with no protection and it worked fine. Back to the internet I go to buy a new protection circuit!